# not able to send the email -POP3/SMTP in blue prism

Tags: email, smtp, pop3, blueprism

In my "Configure" action inputs (Business Object: Email - POP3/SMTP):-

```
Username: xxx@gmail.com 
password: xxxx
POP3 Server: pop.gmail.com
SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
POP3 Port: 995
SMTP Port: 587
POP3 UseSSL: True
SMTP UseSSL: True
```

> Error:- "Internal: Could not execute code stage because the exception is thrown by code stage: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated"

Tried `SMTP Port: 465` and still facing an error:

> - "Internal: Could not execute code stage because an exception is thrown by code stage. Failure sending mail. - Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you security in google
Login your google account and go to security tab there you find somewhere first Turn On Access for less secure apps in the gmail account.

Hope this will work!